# How to upload image with random name in databse in codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter

Like codeigniter 3 `encryt_name` in file upload

How can I encrypt name of file in codeigniter 4? Help me guys

Answer (score 0):

When retrieving your file you can work with the uploaded file library of CI4 : https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/uploaded_files.html

In this lib you can use the `getRandomName()` function.

> You can generate a cryptographically secure random filename, with the
> current timestamp prepended, with the getRandomName() method. This is
> especially useful to rename files when moving it so that the filename
> is unguessable

https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/files.html?highlight=getrandomname#new-features

You'll eventually get something similar to :

```
// get files from $_FILES
if($imagefile = $this->request->getFiles())
{
   foreach($imagefile['images'] as $img)
   {
        // check if each file is valid and from an HTTP source
      if ($img->isValid() && ! $img->hasMoved())
      {
            // generate a new random name and move the file
           $newName = $img->getRandomName();
           $img->move(WRITEPATH.'uploads', $newName);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: `$newName = $img->getRandomName();` instead of this can we use like this `$newName = time();`